# Могу ли я подключиться к api любого сайта или как либо получить с него информацию?

Tags: api, веб-сайт

Я пишу приложение, которое будет брать информацию с сайта моей школы, и удобно компоновать, показывать какой сейчас урок, когда закончится и в каком он кабинете.
Я так понимаю у сайта должен быть открытый api или что-то вроде того, но вряд ли у моей школы что-то такое есть. Как мне получать нужную для меня информацию с сайта школы.

Comment: Не должен, разработчики вполне могли решить не делать никакой api

Comment: Если у сайта школы есть API, он может быть закрыт. Если так, или если API нет совсем, тогда можно парсить, но там свои проблемы. Я бы вообще парсинг не рассамтривал. Лучше всего у нужного человека в школе уточнить, какие возможности есть для экспорта контента с сайта и от этого уже отталкиваться.